# Powershell - Sync files based on modified time

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to do a one way sync in Powershell based of of modified time but my code below does not seem to work. Any ideas?

```
$Folder1Path = 'D:\test'
$Folder2Path = 'C:\test'


$Folder1Files = Get-ChildItem -Path $Folder1Path
$Folder2Files = Get-ChildItem -Path $Folder2Path

$FileDiffs = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $Folder1Files -DifferenceObject $Folder2Files -Property modifyTimeStamp

$FileDiffs | foreach {
$copyParams = @{
                    'Path' = $_.InputObject.FullName
                    }
                if ($_.SideIndicator -eq '<=')
                {
                    $copyParams.Destination = $Folder2Path
                }

                Copy-Item @copyParams 
       }
```

Comment: 1st the property is `LastWriteTime` ***NOT*** `modifyTimeStamp` 2nd without the `-PassThru` parameter you've got no other properties aside from `SideIndicator`

Comment: Also, since it is implied that both folders have the files already, you are going to turn on the `-force` switch on `Copy-item` cmdlet.

Comment: is there a reason NOT to use robocopy?